# How to do an Elasticsearch SQL query for geo_point data

Tags: elasticsearch, geo, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-sql

I have an ES index which contains a mapping of type `geo_point`.  I want to use the [Elasticsearch SQL](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch-sql) API to do a bounding box query.

I know how to do this [using ES DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-bounding-box-query.html) as per the ES docs.

How would I express this in SQL query form?

In sort what SQL query would [translate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-translate.html) into an equivalent `DSL bounding_box` query?